# How to target element inside #shadow-root?

Tags: html, css, user-experience, shadow-root

I want to change the display style inside of the #shadow-root and am having some trouble targeting it. First question,  is it possible to target it through CSS? Or is it better to do it through JS?

```css
#retirement-services-modal #rs-two-col::shadow(.wrapper) {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="retirement-services-modal">
  <sdf-layout-two-col id="rs-two-col">
    #shadow-root
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="col-1">content goes here</div>
      <div class="col-2">content goes here</div>
    </div>
  </sdf-layout-two-col>
</div>
```

I am trying to target the `.wrapper` inside the `#shadow-root` to add a `display: flex;` and `align-items: center;` .

I tried to target it with `::shadow` but that did not seem to work. I also tried `::part` but that did not seem to work either. Are there any other ways to target it through CSS?

Comment: Instead of copy/pasting HTML result; please rewrite your code to a **working** snippet defining your/a Web Component with shadowDOM. Then we can reply to it with one click. ``::shadow`` won't work, add the ``:part()`` code you tried.

Comment: basically HTML, XML, ...SGML all have these 2 letters **M** and **L** to indicate that they are **M**arkup **L**anguages. CSS is an "emanation" of the property of the `style` attribute of HTML **M**arkup tags, it can only address elements belonging to an HTML tag.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman that unfortunately didn't work. I am trying to rewrite the code as a working snippet but don't seem to see that option there (I am new to Stack Overflow! Let me take one more look.

Answer (score 0):

it may be more efficient and easier to use JS to target and manipulate the content.

```
const el = document.querySelector('#rs-two-col'); // access the outer element
const sh = el.shadowRoot; // access the shadow DOM of the element
sh.querySelector('.wrapper').style.cssText = 'display: flex; align-items: center;'; // access the nested element within the shadow DOM and change the CSS property of the element
```

Comment: Fine for **existing** DOM nodes. But what if a new node with a ``.wrapper`` enters the DOM? How are you going to change that then? If the Web Component creator gives you a ``part`` _hook_ (pun intended) you have the technology to do it all with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using `part`

```html
<style>
  host-element::part(foo){
    border:10px dashed green;
  }
  div {
    border:20px solid red; /* not applied to shadowDOM */
  }
</style>

<host-element>
  <template shadowrootmode="open">
    <style>
      :host {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100vw;
        background:hotpink;
      }
      .wrapper {
        text-align:center
      }
    </style>
    <div part="foo" class="wrapper">
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
  </template>
  <h2>LightDOM content slotted in shadowDOM</h2>
</host-element>
```

Note: Above **Declarative shadowDOM** notation `shadowrootmode` is not available in FireFox yet:
https://caniuse.com/declarative-shadow-dom